# Reading Text file and adding the objects into an Array

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have a Contact class that basically just holds information of a contact. We store the contact object in an array.

I had to write the array into a text file, and I knew how to do that, but now I must read that file and store the objects back into an array, and I'm stuck!

Note, ContactList Below also uses class Contact, which just basically has get/set methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;

public class ContactList{
    int ptr = -1;   
    Contact[] list;
    int contactLength;
    public ContactList(){//second constructor needed
        list=new Contact[20];
        contactLength=20;
        for(int i =0;i<20;i++){
            list[i]=null;
        }
    }
    public ContactList(int length){//second constructor needed
        list=new Contact[length];
        contactLength=length;
        for(int i =0;i<length;i++){
            list[i]=null;
        }
    }
    public boolean add(Contact c){
        boolean found = false;
        int i = 0;
        while(!found&&i<20){
            if (list[i]==null){
                list[i]=c;
                found=true;
                ptr=i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return found;
    }
    public Contact find(String name){
        boolean found=false;
        int i =0;
        while(i<contactLength&&!found){
            ptr++;
            if(ptr==contactLength){
                ptr=0;
            }
            if(list[ptr]!=null){
                if (list[ptr].getName().contains(name)){
                    found=true;
                    return list[ptr];
                }
            }   
            i++;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public Contact remove(){
        Contact current= list[ptr];
        list[ptr]=null;
        return current;
    }
    public void displayContacts(){
        for(int i =0;i<contactLength;i++){
            if(list[i]!=null){
                System.out.println(list[i].toString());
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Empty:");//"Name:\nAddress:\nPhone\nComments:"
            }
        }
    }



public boolean write (String fileName){
    PrintWriter p = null; 
    try {
p = new PrintWriter(new File(fileName));
} catch (Exception e) {
return false;
}
for(int i =0;i<contactLength;i++){
    if(list[i]!=null){
        p.println(list[i].toString());
    }}
    p.close();

return true; 
}
```

```
public class Contact {
  private String name;
  private long phone;
  private String address;
  private String comments;

  public void setName( String name){
    this.name =name;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }

  public void setPhone(long phone){
    this.phone=phone;
  }

  public long getPhone(){
    return phone;
  }

  public void setAddress(String address){
    this.address= address;
  }

  public String getAddress(){
    return address;
  }

  public void setComments( String comments){
    this.comments= comments;
  }

  public String getComments(){
    return comments;
  }


  public String toString(){
    return ("Name:\t\t"+name+"\nAddress:\t"+address+"\nPhone Number:\t"+phone+"\nComments:\t"+comments +"\n");
  }

  public Contact(String name, long phone, String address, String comments){
    this.name=name;
    this.phone=phone;
    this.address=address;
    this.comments=comments;
  }
  public boolean equals(Contact other){
    if (this.name!=other.name){
      return false;
    }
    if (this.phone!=other.phone){
      return false;
    }
    if (this.address!=other.address){
      return false;
    }
    if (this.comments!=other.comments){
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Here is what I have so far...

```
public boolean read(String fileName){


Scanner s = null; 
try {
s = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
} catch (Exception e) { // returns false if fails to find fileName
return false;
}

for(int i=0; i)

}
```

And YES I must use array! No lists! And nothing fancy please, this is an intro class, I won't understand it. Just scanner.

Comment: You've posted essentially, "here are some general requirements and here is some unexplained code. Oh and please give me code without Lists...". Please. Put some effort into the asking including -- showing where you've attempted to solve the issue, just isn't working with your attempt, just what concepts confuse you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Smh, nothing pleases you guys. If I don't provide code they say, "We didn't see your code, or you didn't write anything." I provided all the code so it is easy to follow, and broke down where I was stuck... Give me a break

Comment: You've chosen a format that is impossible to parse reliably (unless there are strong constraints on what the elements of a contact can contain). You'd better use JSON or XML to save the contacts. That's trivial to parse back to a contact list. Imagine, for example, that the comments of a contact contains the String representation of another contact. How could you parse that?

Comment: @MSK: Rather than shaking your head, consider putting some effort into explaining your problem in greater detail. Surely you can't fault anyone for asking for this, now can you?

Comment: You don't need to set all the entries of a newly-allocated array to `null`. They are `null` to begin with.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sure, So what don't you understand?

Comment: You've got one item per line of `Name`, `Address`, `Phone Number`, and `Comments`, with a colon and some tabs after each, and you need to read these in and parse them, but it doesn't look like you've tried to write any code to do that.

Comment: @MSK Giving us "all the code" is only slightly better than none.  You should take the time to boil your program down into a [mcve] that contains the code that demonstrates your problem, and *nothing else*. 99% of the time, just the act of trying to clean your code up enough to post a high quality question will lead you to find your error yourself.

Comment: Read four lines by calling `Scanner::nextLine` four times, then strip off everything up to the first colon (found using `String::indexOf`), then strip leading and trailing whitespace with `String::trim` and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: @azurefrog Buddy, with all do respect, how could I have provided any less code without this making sense? I ALWAYS get an angry community either way..

Comment: You could have simply provided a short sample of the file you're trying to read, and the code you've written so far to read it. We don't need to see your Contact class or the code that originally wrote the file. Just, "I'm trying to parse this text file with names, addresses, phone numbers, and comments. Here's the code I've written to parse them, but I can't ..." and the specific piece you're having trouble with.

Comment: @azurefrog....http://image.prntscr.com/image/03965773eb5c4d2b89e19e1a2ae41347.png

Comment: What @DavidConrad said. That's a great description of what a good question might look like.

Comment: @DavidConrad I know how to read the lines in the file, but how would I store them in an array of object type Contacts?

Comment: If you know how to read the lines in the file, why isn't that much present in the code you've written so far?

Comment: @azurefrog Been there done that, get yelled at regardless. Can't please everyone I guess.

Comment: @DavidConrad I mean that isn't the thing that is throwing me off. And, because I don't know if it would be in a loop, or how the structure would be...

Comment: Of course it would be in a loop. There's more than one contact in the file, isn't there? And the `ContactList` has an `add` method. And `Contact` has a constructor that takes a name, number, address, and comment. ???

Comment: @DavidConrad Why are you talking down to me? Is it illegal to get stuck? Man, have some manners. No one is forcing you to help, but don't treat me like an idiot for asking a question.

Comment: That's a good point. No one is forcing anyone to help.

Comment: Disgusting community

Answer (score 0):

I see the pros and cons in the comment section, what about putting an end to the debate, given how you write I'm guessing you will need something like:

```
   public static void read(String fileName){
     try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))){
         String line = null;
         String[] contact = new String[4];
         int contactCounter = 0;
         int buffer = 0;
         while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
             buffer = line.split("\t").length - 1;
             contact[contactCounter] = line.split("\t")[buffer];
             contactCounter++;
             if (contactCounter == 3){
                 new Contact(contact[0], contact[1], contact[2], contact[3]);
                 contactCounter == 0;
             }

         }

     } catch (IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

**I strongly suggest you improve how you serialize your Contact** because this format is a mess, especially having not clear boundaries, the best I could figure was counting 4 EOL to create a new Contact.

Maybe have a look at csv format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values